# AutoMapper : Error when mapping between two lists

Tags: list, automapper, abp, icollection

#### Source/destination types

```cs
public partial class MailMessage
{
    public List<MailMessageRecipient> MailMessageRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class CreateDraftInputDto : EntityDto<Guid>
{
    [Required]
    public List<CreateDraftInput_ToRecipientDto> MailMessageRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class CreateDraftInput_ToRecipientDto : EntityDto<Guid>
    {
        public bool ToRecipient { get; set; }
        public bool CcRecipient { get; set; }
        public bool CciRecipient { get; set; }
    }

public partial class MailMessageRecipient : Entity.Entity, ITenantMailAddress
{
    public Guid MailAddressId { get; set; }

    public Guid MailMessageId { get; set; }

    public bool ToRecipient { get; set; }
    public bool CcRecipient { get; set; }
    public bool CciRecipient { get; set; }
}
```

#### Mapping configuration

```cs
CreateMap<CreateDraftInput_ToRecipientDto, MailMessageRecipient>(MemberList.None);

CreateMap<CreateDraftInputDto, MailMessage>(MemberList.None);
```

#### Version: 12.0.0.0

#### Expected behavior

Before mapping, I get the MailMessage from my repository including the MailMessageRecipients, they are having already their MailAddressId and MailMessageId set. I expect those fields to remaining themselves as they are not in my DTO.

#### Actual behavior

These fields are set to Guid.Empty. I have tried many tests and some work : if I declare my MailMessageRecipients inside MailMessage as an ICollection<MailMessageRecipient>, and then do this :
ObjectMapper.Map(input.MailMessageRecipients, mailMessage.MailMessageRecipients.ToList());
It works, as well as converting this ICollection toArray(). But when it's declared as a List inside my Entity, it doesn't work anymore.

Thing is I can't always convert ToList() this way, because I need to do the mapping on the parent which is more like
ObjectMapper.Map(CreateDraftInputDtoInstance, MailMessageInstance);

#### Steps to reproduce

```cs
MailMessage mailMessage = await _mailMessageRepository.GetMailMessage(input.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
ObjectMapper.Map(input.MailMessageRecipients, mailMessage.MailMessageRecipients);
```

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.